# Why vba doesn't move shape in the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to move a shape (textbox) in `Sheet1` from `Sheet2`, but it's not moving at all. I can't figure out why.

```
Sub MoveTextboxInMatrix(priority, TextboxName)

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

On Error Resume Next

Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape
Dim left As Single
Dim top As Single

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix")

ws.Unprotect "Password"

Set s = ws.Shapes(TextboxName)
        
left = 0
top = 0

MsgBox priority
        
'high
If priority = "HIGH" Then

    'Int(lowerbound + Rnd * ( upperbound – lowerbound + 1 ) )'
    left = Int(122 + Rnd * (611 - 120 + 1))
    top = Int(78 + Rnd * (500 - 70 + 1))


    MsgBox "high _ " & left & "  " & top

'medium
ElseIf priority = "MEDIUM" Then

    'Int(lowerbound + Rnd * ( upperbound – lowerbound + 1 ) )'
    left = Int(685 + Rnd * (1178 - 685 + 1))
    top = Int(78 + Rnd * (500 - 70 + 1))
    
    MsgBox "med _ " & left & "  " & top
    
    
'low
ElseIf priority = "LOW" Then

    'Int(lowerbound + Rnd * ( upperbound – lowerbound + 1 ) )'
    left = Int(1250 + Rnd * (1800 - 1200 + 1))
    top = Int(78 + Rnd * (500 - 70 + 1))
    
    MsgBox "low _ " & left & "  " & top


End If

'move the box
MsgBox "moving from " & s.left & " to " & left
With s
    .IncrementLeft left
    .IncrementTop top
End With

ws.Protect "Password"

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

End Sub

It does show all the message boxes, but it still doesn't move the shape. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried the program removing ``On Error Resume Next``? Maybe some error occurs while the execution. When I run your program, it worked perfectly fine. So, I guess a mistake of sheet name or textbox name...

Comment: Yes, I have. but it still doesn't do anything. I used similar code to rename the shape which works fine. `MsgBox s.Name` shows nothing and later `s.left` errors as stating `invalid use of property`. I changed to `s.left` from `s.incrementleft`

Comment: I figured it out. I made a mistake in setting the proper `TextboxName`, so it was never finding it.